# Where is the luggage storage in Barcelona Sants station?

Tags: trains, luggage-storage, barcelona

Thanks to the ever-excellent [Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_offices_&_lockers_in_Spain), I've found out that [there are luggage lockers available at Barcelona's Sants main station](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_offices_&_lockers_in_Spain):

> Barcelona Sants has luggage lockers, open 05:30-23:00 daily.  Small locker €3.60, large €5.20.  There's an X-ray check of all bags entering locker area.

It has been a year or so since I last took the train from Sants, but I can't remember seeing any signs for luggage storage. I also recall it's a fairly large station.

Does anyone know exactly where in the station the luggage storage is, and/or if it is well sign-posted from inside the station?

Comment: Not in the station, but close we found http://www.lockerbarcelona.com/ to be very good with helpful staff that spoke English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked a friend who live in Barcelona to check it.

The place is located in the main hall next to McDonalds (Sants station).

**The address is:**
Carrer del Rector Triadó, 75.

You can see the place in Google Street view, just [click here](https://www.google.co.il/maps/@41.3786839,2.1402792,3a,32.8y,101.1h,82.98t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sOpZbwceB0hMbVvo50bl9Rg!2e0!3e2!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1).

Answer (score -1):

You can also leave your luggage at ChillZone Lockers Barcelona, charge your smartphone and change your clothes in their cabins.
You can find more information on www.chillzone.me The adress is Carrer Salavador Espriu, 61 (B 1-1) 08005 Barcelona.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It's great to have this as information and an option for travelers, but please disclose your affiliation with the company (use the edit function), so that it's not removed as spam.

Answer (score -1):

I just used Stasher.com to store a few bags. They have a few locations just outside Sants - was so easy, just booked and paid online and then dropped my bags off! Have used Stasher elsewhere as well and always had a good experience so fully recommend for whenever you need luggage storage.